# What does "list" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

> When it is necessary to have electrical devices which come into
>   contact with water, such devices shall be designed and **listed** for use
>   in water.

I looked up a dictionary, but couldn't find any definition that fits in this context. What does "listed" exactly mean? Does it mean that the device shall be labeled for use in water?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To list something means to include that thing in a list. If something is listed for use in water, it is on a list, possibly kept by a safety agency, of devices that may be used in water.